# SQL statement not working in Oracle Database

Tags: sql, oracle

```
SELECT t.*
FROM test
INNER JOIN apple a ON a.id = t.id
WHERE t.type IN (12,13) AND t.file= '1234'
AND TO_DATE(t.Date,'YYYY/MM/DD') >= TO_DATE(t.Date,'2020/01/01')
```

Error is

> Date Format not Recognised

Comment: what's the error? and what are \ ?

Comment: Check the TO_DATE function in Oracle.

Comment: Why are you storing DATE values in a `varchar` column? That's a **really** bad idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problems I can see immediately are as follows:

1. in your second to_date, '2020/01/01' is an actual date; Oracle *to_date* requires a **date format** in that location. I'm understanding you want to include rows with t.Date value since start of 1st January 2020, in which case change the *to_date* command to read as follows:

> to_date('2020/01/01','YYYY/MM/DD')

2. you reference **t** in your query but it is not set up as an alias for "test". It should read:

> SELECT t.* from test **t**

eg.

```
SELECT t.* 
from test t
     INNER JOIN apple a on a.id = t.id
WHERE t.type IN (12,13)
AND t.file = '1234'
AND TO_DATE(t.Date,'YYYY/MM/DD') >= to_date('2020/01/01','YYYY/MM/DD')
```

As an aside I would also recommend that if possible you change the data type of column *t.date* in your table *test* to the Oracle **date** type rather than a string as among other benefits date arithmetic becomes much easier.